# php mysql duplicate insert when refresh page

Tags: php, mysql

i have form to get some data and file from user and insert it to mysql DB

and its done. but when i get message success and file is uploaded and if i refresh page same data duplicate inside DB

i don't want duplicate data inside DB when i refresh page

this is my code :

```
<?php
$Name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nameofresearch']) ?
$_POST['nameofresearch'] : '';
$Dates=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateofstart']) ?
$_POST['dateofstart'] : '';
$Datee=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateofend']) ?
$_POST['dateofend'] : '';
$budget=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['budget']) ?
$_POST['budget'] : '';
$Names=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['requestedby']) ?
$_POST['requestedby'] : '';
$executingagency=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['executingagency']) ?
$_POST['executingagency'] : '';
$projectstatus =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['projectstatus']) ?
$_POST['projectstatus'] : '';
$projectmanager =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['projectmanager']) ?
$_POST['projectmanager'] : '';
$briefdes =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['briefdes']) ?
$_POST['briefdes'] : '';
if($_POST['expert'][0]) { $first_expert   = $_POST['expert'][0]; } else { $first_expert  = 0; }
if($_POST['expert'][1]) { $second_expert  = $_POST['expert'][1]; } else { $second_expert  = 0; }
if($_POST['expert'][2]) { $third_expert   = $_POST['expert'][2]; } else { $third_expert  = 0; }

include("../config.php");
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'])) { 
$fname = "ERI_db/".date("H-i-s").strstr($_FILES['fileupload']['name'],'.'); 
} else { echo "<BR>No file uploaded<BR>"; }

$sql="INSERT INTO " . ERI_TABLE . "    (id,nameofresearch,dateofstart,dateofend,budget,requestedby,executingagency, projectstatus,projectmanager,briefdes,filename,expert1,expert2,expert3) 
               VALUES(NULL, '$Name', '$Dates', '$Datee', '$budget', '$Names','$executingagency', '$projectstatus', '$projectmanager', '$briefdes','$fname','$first_expert','$second_expert','$third_expert')";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
if($result)
{
    echo "<BR><b>Successful<BR>";
    echo "<BR>";
    //----------------------------------------
    if($_FILES['fileupload']['size']>0)
    {
        if(!in_array($_FILES['fileupload']['type'],$exten)){ $r.="امتداد الملف خطا -    <br>";} 
        if(file_exists($dir.$_FILES['fileupload']['name'])){ $r.="الملف موجودة مسبقا -<br>";}
        if($_FILES['fileupload']['size']>$bigsize){ $r.="حجم الملف اكبر من المسموح به -<br>";}
    }
    if($r)
    {
        echo $r;
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        if($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'])
        {
            copy($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'],$dir.$fname);
            echo "<BR>File is uploaded<BR>";
            // echo "<BR>" . $dir.$fname . "<BR>"; // Print path to file 
            echo "<BR>";
        }}
} else {
echo "<BR>ERROR<BR>";
echo mysql_error();
}
```

How can i do ?
please describe solution

Answer (score 1):

> and its done. but when i get message success and file is uploaded and if i refresh page same data duplicate inside DB

You should redirect page to another location after file uploaded with **success** or **error** message to prevent this issue.

Answer (score 0):

HI After successful execution of query just redirect control to some other page or to the same page

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `POST` method, you should redirect the saving process page to a new page for your display of Success or Fail.

EDIT:

Add something like this after `$result=mysql_query($sql);`

```
if($result){
    //If success code
    header('Location: page.php?msg=success');
}
else {
    //If error code
    header('Location: page.php?msg=error');
}
```

In page.php, can be something like this...

```
if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
    $msg=$_GET['msg'];
    if($msg=="success"){
        //Your success message
    }
    else if($msg=="error"){
        //Your error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@nasr25, it should be something simple PHP redirection script

```
header("Location: Your redirection page path"); /* Redirect browser */
```

exit();

**Ref.Link:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
$Name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nameofresearch']) ?
$_POST['nameofresearch'] : '';
$Dates=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateofstart']) ?
$_POST['dateofstart'] : '';
$Datee=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateofend']) ?
$_POST['dateofend'] : '';
$budget=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['budget']) ?
$_POST['budget'] : '';
$Names=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['requestedby']) ?
$_POST['requestedby'] : '';
$executingagency=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['executingagency']) ?
$_POST['executingagency'] : '';
$projectstatus =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['projectstatus']) ?
$_POST['projectstatus'] : '';
$projectmanager =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['projectmanager']) ?
$_POST['projectmanager'] : '';
$briefdes =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['briefdes']) ?
$_POST['briefdes'] : '';
if($_POST['expert'][0]) { $first_expert   = $_POST['expert'][0]; } else { $first_expert  = 0; }
if($_POST['expert'][1]) { $second_expert  = $_POST['expert'][1]; } else { $second_expert  = 0; }
if($_POST['expert'][2]) { $third_expert   = $_POST['expert'][2]; } else { $third_expert  = 0; }

include("../config.php");
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'])) { 
$fname = "ERI_db/".date("H-i-s").strstr($_FILES['fileupload']['name'],'.'); 
} else { echo "<BR>No file uploaded<BR>"; }

$sql="INSERT INTO " . ERI_TABLE . "    (id,nameofresearch,dateofstart,dateofend,budget,requestedby,executingagency, projectstatus,projectmanager,briefdes,filename,expert1,expert2,expert3) 
               VALUES(NULL, '$Name', '$Dates', '$Datee', '$budget', '$Names','$executingagency', '$projectstatus', '$projectmanager', '$briefdes','$fname','$first_expert','$second_expert','$third_expert')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
{
    echo "<BR><b>Successful<BR>";
    echo "<BR>";
    //----------------------------------------
    if($_FILES['fileupload']['size']>0)
    {
        if(!in_array($_FILES['fileupload']['type'],$exten)){ $r.="امتداد الملف خطا -    <br>";} 
        if(file_exists($dir.$_FILES['fileupload']['name'])){ $r.="الملف موجودة مسبقا -<br>";}
        if($_FILES['fileupload']['size']>$bigsize){ $r.="حجم الملف اكبر من المسموح به -<br>";}
    }
    if($r)
    {
        echo $r;
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        if($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'])
        {
            copy($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'],$dir.$fname);
            echo "<BR>File is uploaded<BR>";
            // echo "<BR>" . $dir.$fname . "<BR>"; // Print path to file 
            echo "<BR>";
        }}
} else {
echo "<BR>ERROR<BR>";
echo mysql_error();
}
unset($_POST);
}else{
// redirect to your page.
}
```